# Angular RouteGuard http mapping memory leak

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm making an Angular application with routeGuard access. The routeGuard asks the backend service which roles the current user has. This works as expected. When the user stays on a page for a certain amount of time without doing anything and then comes back to navigate to another route, the backend server crashes (WebApi).

I think there is still a subscription or observable running in the background with an http request from the routeGuard to my backend service. The backend services uses IIS, so it will go in IDLE modus after 20min. The user then comes back but the request is not found or goes into error modus?

I tried to use pipe(take(1)) and it seems to work for the moment, but I want to be 100 % sure this was the problem.

Does below method has some memory leaks or does it keep the observable alive?

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if(this.backendService.isAuthenticated) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return this.http.get<User>(this.appConfig.user)
        .pipe(
            map(
                (user) => {
                    this.backendService.initializeUser(user);
                    return this.backendService.isUserInitialized();
                }
            ),
            catchError(<T>(error: any, result?: T) => {
                this.backendService.showError()
                return of(true);
            })
        )
        ;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of your problem is something else. All HTTP request automatically unsubscribe (it is still advised to unsubscribe them manually) so I dont think you have some subscription running that give you a memory leak.

HTTP request are Finite Observable and you dont have to unsubscribe these (Still better to do so if possible).

Comment: In this routeguard I don't use 'subscribe', so the observable is not unscubscribed either. (I think)